# MS Excel 2010 - XY Plot and Bar Chart Together and Dates don't match

Tags: excel, bar-chart

I have an XY plot in Excel with some water level data, and I wanted to add a set of precipitation data as bars to help correlate changes in water level. However, there is no option to add dates for the precipitation data, and the bars don't have the same scale as the water level data. I tried using Julian calendar dates to resolve the issue, but that didn't help.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Water level and precipitation both as Y vs dates as X?

Make a line chart of both sets of data. Right-click on the precip series in the chart, choose Change Series Chart Type, and select a column type. If the scale is way off, you can format the precip to go on the secondary axis, so it will be plotted on the right axis scale.

Comment: Thanks Jon. This is what I had already done, but when you create a bar series in an XY plot, you lose the ability to select a date range. I was able to manually adjust my axis values using the 1904 dating system and it works that way. But thanks for your response!!!

Comment: No, make a LINE chart with both series, which will end up with a Date axis, then convert the one series to Columns, which will not affect the axis.